# ElasticSearch pagination through pyes. Offset ignored

Tags: python, pagination, elasticsearch

I'm working off the pyes usage example [here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyes/)

I'm indexing *test-index* with four documents and querying later using different offsets. The **start** parameter doesn't change the offset for me, I keep getting the same results regardless of its value. Why is this happening?

```
from pyes import *
conn = ES(["localhost:9200"])
try:
    conn.delete_index('test-index') 
except:
    pass

conn.create_index('test-index')

mapping = {u'name': {'boost': 1.0,
                 'index': 'analyzed',
                 'store': 'yes',
                 'type': u'string',
                 "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"},
       u'title': {'boost': 1.0,
                 'index': 'analyzed',
                 'store': 'yes',
                 'type': u'string',
                 "term_vector" : "with_positions_offsets"},
       u'pos': {'store': 'yes',
                 'type': u'integer'},
       u'uuid': {'boost': 1.0,
                'index': 'not_analyzed',
                'store': 'yes',
                'type': u'string'}}

conn.put_mapping("test-type", {'properties':mapping}, ["test-index"])

conn.index({"name":"Joe Tester", "uuid":"11111", "position":1}, "test-index", "test-type", 1)
conn.index({"name":"Bill Baloney", "uuid":"22222", "position":2}, "test-index", "test-type", 2)
conn.index({"name":"Joe Joseph", "uuid":"33333", "position":3}, "test-index", "test-type", 3)
conn.index({"name":"Last Joe", "uuid":"44444", "position":4}, "test-index", "test-type", 4)

conn.refresh(["test-index"])

q = TermQuery("name", "joe")
r0 = conn.search(q, indices = ["test-index"], start=0, size=1)
r1 = conn.search(q, indices = ["test-index"], start=1, size=1)
r2 = conn.search(q, indices = ["test-index"], start=2, size=1)

print('0: {0}'.format(r0['hits']['hits']))
print('1: {0}'.format(r1['hits']['hits']))
print('2: {0}'.format(r2['hits']['hits']))
```

output:

```
$ python pagination.py 
0: [{u'_score': 0.19178301, u'_type': u'test-type', u'_id': u'4', u'_source': {u'position': 4, u'name': u'Last Joe', u'uuid': u'44444'}, u'_index': u'test-index'}]
1: [{u'_score': 0.19178301, u'_type': u'test-type', u'_id': u'4', u'_source': {u'position': 4, u'name': u'Last Joe', u'uuid': u'44444'}, u'_index': u'test-index'}]
2: [{u'_score': 0.19178301, u'_type': u'test-type', u'_id': u'4', u'_source': {u'position': 4, u'name': u'Last Joe', u'uuid': u'44444'}, u'_index': u'test-index'}]
```

**My pyes version is 0.16.0**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in how the request was sent to ES, although I'm still not clear on why it failed.

Instead of sending the queries directly to ES like I did originally:

```
r0 = conn.search(q, indexes = ["test-index"], start=0, size=1)
r1 = conn.search(q, indexes = ["test-index"], start=1, size=1)
r2 = conn.search(q, indexes = ["test-index"], start=2, size=1)
```

I wrapped my queries in a pyes.query.Search object:

```
r0 = conn.search(Search(q, start=0, size=1), indexes = ["test-index"])
r1 = conn.search(Search(q, start=1, size=1), indexes = ["test-index"])
r2 = conn.search(Search(q, start=2, size=1), indexes = ["test-index"])
```

That worked, see the output below:

```
0s: [{u'_score': 0.19178301, u'_type': u'test-type', u'_id': u'4', u'_source': {u'position': 4, u'name': u'Last Joe', u'uuid': u'44444'}, u'_index': u'test-index'}]
1s: [{u'_score': 0.19178301, u'_type': u'test-type', u'_id': u'1', u'_source': {u'position': 1, u'name': u'Joe Tester', u'uuid': u'11111'}, u'_index': u'test-index'}]
2s: [{u'_score': 0.19178301, u'_type': u'test-type', u'_id': u'3', u'_source': {u'position': 3, u'name': u'Joe Joseph', u'uuid': u'33333'}, u'_index': u'test-index'}]
```

Comment: I'm having troubles with this and getting the no query registered exception when elastic search parses the search. What version of pyes where you using?

Comment: The 'indexes' param is confusing, since 'indices' is used in the pyes test cases. 'indices' is ignored and all indexes are searched. If they have the same mapping or you only have one index that's fine, if not, you'll see an error.

Answer (score 2):

Ensure your using a search type of [Query then Fetch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/search-type.html).

Comment: Yeah, it's very easy to mix `QUERY_AND_FETCH` and `QUERY_THEN_FETCH`.